# My Model Wont Convert (with the mixamo root baker plug in)

Tags: modeling

So I have a model, however when I try and batch convert it with the mixamo root baker plug in it wont convert and comes up with this ERROR message[image: From the console] help is greatly appreciated. Thxs

Comment: Please [include error messages as text instead of a screenshot](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2788/5705).  Also just the error isn't much info for us to go on, please add some more details about the model you're exporting.

Comment: So I have a character I want to batch convert right, so I try and batch convert it (with the mixamo root baker plug in) and that error comes up. That's all I know